# Microcontroller to control 18V Source

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, mosfet, switches, teensy

I'm Designing a circuit to help calibrate a programable rotary encoder, essentially 18V @ 20ma must be supplied to a certain pin on the rotary encoder to set its position.

I am trying to use a N-Channel MOSFET as a switch for this pin to be controlled by a teensy 3.3V High to the gate.

Everything I have found online has pointed to the fact that the load and Vcc should be on the Drain side of the MOSFET and ground on the source side. However this cant be possible since the the rotary encoder must be able to be read throughout all this and thus I cant interrupt connection between the ground pin and the battery ground.

I have attached an image below to show what I think would be a working circuit and would like to know if this would cause me any issues.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work. You'll get a volt or two at the source of the N-channel MOSFET.

You need something called a "high side driver". For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQGw8b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could also substitute P-channel and N-channel MOSFETs and leave out R3, assuming Q2 is okay with 18V Vgs.

To make the source follower (your original circuit) work you need to give the MOSFET enough Vgs that it turns on properly (which generally requires 5 or 10V) so you'd need to drive the gate with 23 to 28V, not 3.3V.. and that would create additional issues with gate-source breakdown voltage limits which are typically 8 to 20V and should not be exceeded for even an instant).

Comment: I see how what you sent works however I don't understand why Q1 would turn on to the 3.3V but not Q2. Why cant I just connect the pin directly to Q2? Also, is there any motive behind the Resistor value choices, as well as the transistor types. Thanks!

Comment: If you connect the 3.3V pin directly to Q2 (BJT) you will likely destroy the MCU or whatever is driving it. It would be pulled up to about 17.3V, causing damage.

Comment: Q1 shifts the voltage and Q2 drives the output. The resistor choices are 'okay' for the task with 20mA out, giving Q2 almost 1/10 the load current so ensuring it will be well into saturation. They could be optimized in other ways, but having all values the same is a kind of optimization. The transistor types are inexpensive, universally available 'jellybean' parts. You could use other types such as 2N4401/2N4403, SS8050/SS8550, BC847/BC857 etc.

Comment: The general reason why it won't work is that Vgs or Vbe is what turns the transistor 'on' and with the load in the source or emitter, the source or emitter voltage increases, reducing the Vgs or Vbe, so it cannot turn on fully (or hardly at all, in this case).